# ImportError: cannot import name 'ControlType' from 'libcamera' (unknown location)

Tags: opencv, libcamera

I'm relatively new to Raspberry Pi and I am having trouble running a python code on raspberry pi. The code I'm trying to run is as shown below:

```
import cv2
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera2 import Picamera2

camera = Picamera2()
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

cv2.namedWindow("Frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
camera.close()
```

I have installed all of the necessary libraries however, when trying to run the code, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raspberry/project/myenv/gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    from picamera2 import Picamera2
  File "/home/raspberry/project/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .configuration import CameraConfiguration, StreamConfiguration
  File "/home/raspberry/project/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera2/configuration.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .controls import Controls
  File "/home/raspberry/project/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/picamera2/controls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from libcamera import ControlType, Rectangle, Size
ImportError: cannot import name 'ControlType' from 'libcamera' (unknown location)
```

I have searched for [similar problems and solutions](https://github.co/raspberrypi/picamera2/issues/218) however, they haven't been of much help for me.

I am currently using **Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5**

Python version: **3.9.2**

RaspberryPi Image: **Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux**

The camera i'm using is Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 (**IMX708**)

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Importing both `picamera` and `picamera2` doesn't sound like a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

My test script was very simple -

```
from picamera2 import Picamera2
picam2 = Picamera2()
```

But my error was slightly different -

```
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'Orientation' from 'libcamera'
```

I was able to solve it by installing python3-libcamera

```
sudo apt install python3-libcamera
```

Note that before installing python3-libcamera -

1. I was able to invoke 'libcamera-hello' without any issues
2. /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libcamera existed, but was lacking
   the '_libcamera..so' file

[image: _libcamera..so didn't exist in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libcamera]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be when installing picamera2 (and 'numpy' for whatever reason) via 'pip3'. I had to uninstall both via 'pip3':

`sudo pip3 uninstall numpy picamera2`

and reinstall them via 'apt':

`sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-picamera2`

After those changes everything worked for me.

Hope this helps.